# Windows cannot see the installed dll file

Tags: windows-10, dll

I want to install a software and it asked me to install a dll file first and i added that dll file to system32 folder but after that the software still asking me to install the dll file so what am i missing here ?

Comment: Placing DLLs in a directory does not install them. It is odd for software to require manual installation of DLLs. I would strongly suggest you read the documentation for this product to see if it contains further information.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying it to C:\windows\SysWOW64 instead.

Comment: Placing DLLs inside directories does not "install" them. Windows DLLs must be registered.

Comment: All I know is that this has worked for me before.